# blender addon panel gradient display

Tags: add-on

I am trying to display a gradient in an addon panel but it display everything on one line so it's useless.
[image: code sample]

What I have:
[image: not ok]

What I want:
[image: ok]

Comment: Hello, could you add little more information about `sn_layout` ? Note it's good practice to provide code in text format rather than image for helpers

Comment: forget it. need a tutorial each time I have to post code here. I just can't get it. So hard to ask a question here... I'll find by myself

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. But you are not entitled to anything when coming here to ask a question. Just as I am not entitled to reading perfect questions :) We helpers are dedicating our free time to help other people, I feel like you could try to facilitate the process when asked to. Anyways, finding things by yourself is also a good way to advance in a particular topic. Cheers :)